# Why there is space above my list?

Tags: android, xml

This is my problem: [image: image1]

Why there is a space above the list?

This is my xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_height="459dp" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I think there is because androidstudio shows me the **"androhouse2.0"** toolbar, how can I remove it? See this picture:
[image: image2]

an other question, how can I change color of "notific bar"? (in first picture is white, I need blue)

thnks

Comment: what is a purpose of `ImageView` above `TabLayout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do match_parent viewpager hight

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: I do but nothing.. there is this "space"

Comment: You have fixed view pager height  android:layout_height="459dp". You should change it match_parent

Comment: I do, 459dp was a mistake, but there is space too like my first photo

Answer (score 1):

For changing the notificationBar color use

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        Window window = activity.getWindow();

window.setStatusBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.notificationBarColor));
```